# Can I get a French visa in order to join the French Foreign Legion?

Tags: visas, france, kenyan-citizens

Is joining the French Foreign Legion a legit reason to acquire a visa to France?

Comment: What's your nationality?

Comment: My nationality is Kenyan

Comment: Also, it is worth considering *why* you want to join the FFL, and why joining your own country's army isn't an option.

Comment: Not an answer but worth reading: [FFL FAQ](https://www.legion-recrute.com/en/faq-frequently-asked-questions)

Answer (score 10):

**Not really**.  First of all, the Foreign Legion provides [no visa assistance whatsoever](http://www.legion-recrute.com/mdl/info_seul.php?id=6&block=3&titre=administratives), full stop:

> La Légion Etrangère n'effectue aucune démarche en vue de l'obtention
>   d'un visa ou autorisation de sortie du territoire des candidats à
>   l'engagement.

So you will need to get a visa to France (or another Schengen country) on your own merits.

There are various anecdotal claims on the Internet claiming that a) stating that you want to join the Foreign Legion is automatic grounds for visa rejection, and b) the Foreign Legion accepts even applicants who are in the country illegally.  I can't find any official reference either way, and both seem unlikely.

Comment: It seems that the Foreign Legion do accept applicants who are in the country illegally. On the same page @jpatokal mentions, you can read that people from outside Schengen zone need a 'valid passport (only)'. The stress on 'only' means to me that no valid visa is required.

Comment: so you mean to say, how you get into France doesn't really matter(illegal or legal) if you wanna join the FFL so bad?

Comment: @blackendian : this other page http://legion-recrute.com/mdl/info_seul.php?id=40&block=26&titre=quels-documents-dois-je-prendre-pour-le-recrutement also mentions only a valid passport, and does not mention a valid visa. Notice that I am not sure that serving will give you a valid visa at the end of the service (whose minimal initial duration is five years). Notice also there are medical and physical tests to achieve.

Comment: @audionuma Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence: the page also doesn't say anything about not being on the run from the police because you murdered your family with an axe, but I'm pretty sure that would be a problem in practice.  I don't think the "valid passport only" is meant to imply more than that a *work permit* is not required.

Comment: @jpatokal : I wouldn't suggest to anyone to enter illegally in France based only on my comment.

Comment: The Foreign Legion is surrounded by legends like people who want to start their life from scratch, because they used to be criminals for example, are welcome. So the requirements may indeed be minimal. However, this is kind of a legend, I would not base immigration rules on that.

Comment: Note that you may not need to [give your real identity when enrolling](http://www.legion-recrute.com/mdl/info_seul.php?id=42&block=26&titre=faut-il-obligatoirement-s-engager-sous-identite-declaree) (this is not automatically accepted though) which backs up the idea that you may be present illegally. However, you have to give your real identity after serving one year.

Comment: @lambshaanxy "the recruitment practices of the French Foreign Legion have also led to a somewhat romanticised view of it being a place for disgraced or 'wronged' men looking to leave behind their old lives and start new ones": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Foreign_Legion#Legacy